# Where do I put the gitignore file in a asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, github, gitignore

Hey I am pretty new to git and realized that the bin and debug should not be included when pushing the project. Could anyone tell me where the gitignore file should go? If any one had examples of a basic gitignores for such a project that would also be great! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put it at the root of your git repo, as explained din the [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).

You will find all gitignore examples in this [GitHub project](https://github.com/github/gitignore), but also on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/).

For instance, you can consider this [`.gitignore` for asp.net project](https://gist.github.com/codingoutloud/3318347).
You have also [blog post illustrating the same `.gitignore`](http://samarskyy.blogspot.fr/2012/03/my-git-ignore-for-aspnet.html).

One of the most complete is the one on [github/gitignore VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore).
It does include `bin` and `debug`:

```
# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```